# Microsoft edge and new line

Tags: mysql, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have a field in a mysql database:

```
Clandon Park update March 2017
by Paul cook, Project Director
```

This displays correctly with Firefox and my Kindle Fire, but both Chrome and Microsoft Edge ignore the new line and simply output a single line.   Why t
his difference in behaviour and how do I correct it?

I have tried the various suggestions I have researched (\n, +char(10 + char(13) +, etc) but none of them works.

Comment: There should be a new line after 2017!   Your software also seems to ignore this.

Comment: You would use <br/> (or css white-space: pre) to represent a new line in HTML which will collapse all line sequences to a single space by default.